# Can there be two ids for an object in json api

Tags: java, rest, web-services, json-api

I am using a restful webservice that gives response in json api format. There is a relationship attribute that has id and type params. Based on the id reference it displays values in the included attribute. The id is created after the two requests that process as a final output. Till then I save my data in database as one single object. Now when I fetch the data from database using rest webservice the output shows all the attributes except the included. Which I believe is because it isn't able to find the reference so not getting displayed. But in the database all the values are present perfectly. I am not sure whether json api supports multiple ids for relationship attribute or not.
Example:
Request Body:

```
{
"data": {
        "type": "orders",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "new order",
            "updateDate": "",
            "register":"yes",
            "items":[
                {
                    "description": "newly added item",
                    "type": "new item",
                    "amount": [
                        {
                            "deliveryfee": "123",
                            "mrp": "456"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Response Body:

```
 {
        "data": {
            "type": "orders",
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "new order",
                "updateDate": "",
                
            },
            "relationships": {
                "items": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "items",
                            "id": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "included": [
            {
                "type": "items",
                "id": null,
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "new item",
                    "description": "newly added item",
                    "amount": [
                        {
                            "deliveryfee": "123",
                            "mrp": "456"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Actual Response Body:

```
 {
    "data": {
        "type": "orders",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "new order",
            "updateDate": "",
            
        },
        "relationships": {
            "items": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "items",
                        "id": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure if I understand your question correctly. But let me try to answer.

The combination of a `type` and `id` is used in [JSON API specification](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-identification) to identify a resource:

> Within a given API, each resource object’s `type` and `id` pair MUST identify a single, unique resource.

`null` as used in your example is not a valid value for `id`:

> The values of the `id` and `type` members MUST be strings.

The API may combine multiple identifiers used in its internal database to construct the value used for `id` in a JSON API document as long as it's unique for the given type. This would be a valid `id` value from JSON API specification point of view as long as it's guaranteed to be unique.

```json
{
  "type": "posts":
  "id": "post_id:5,locale:en"
}
```

The API may de-serialize the ID to two different identifiers: A post with the id `5` and a local with the id `"en"`. That would be an internal implementation detail of the API. Consumers should not care if a meaning is encoded within the `id` value.

The request and response bodies given in your question do not fit together. Both contain a field `items`. But in the request body the `items` field is an *attribute*, while its a *relationship* in the response.

It seems as if you are trying to create multiple resources at once. This is not support by JSON API specification v1. It is supported in the third release candidate for v1.1 of the specification through the official extension [Atomic Operations](https://jsonapi.org/ext/atomic/).

Comment: Correct, the items is a separate entity due to business use case we have to merge it into one single response in the form of relationship. I will try the same with v1.1. Thanks